# Is there a way to dynamically load a data provider at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, dataprovider, npgsql

I don't want to modify my machine.config, but I want to use the Npgsql library as a data provider.  I will deploy my application to multiple platforms (including mono) so I would really like the thing to "just work" instead of giving me the error "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider."

Is there a way to "register" Npgsql as a data provider at runtime so this does not happen?

I should clarify that Npgsql works fine without it being in my machine.config for most things, but there are some it does not work well for (like NLog -- the current source of my frustration).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out how to do what I needed done; it's not quite "runtime" but close enough and I didn't have to modify my machine.config.  I added this section to my web.config file:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

...and it started working like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to resort to using Reflection (the code is for Microsoft .NET Framework so you would have to verify if the private field is the same in Mono).

```
using System.Data.Common;

// 1. Initialize the default configuration
DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses();

// 2. Retrieve the configuration table.
var config = (DataTable)typeof(DbProviderFactories).GetField("_providerTable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);

// 3. Add a new entry in the configuration (replace the values with ones for your provider).
DataRow dataRow = config.NewRow();
dataRow["Name"] = "SqlClient Data Provider";
dataRow["InvariantName"] = typeof(SqlConnection).Namespace.ToString();
dataRow["Description"] = ".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer";
dataRow["AssemblyQualifiedName"] = typeof(SqlConnection).AssemblyQualifiedName;
config.Rows.Add(dataRow);
```

Comment: This did not seem to do anything.  Is there perhaps another command required to reinitialize the provider factories list?